# Inequliaty about indefinite integral and measurable function

Tags: measure-theory

$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be Lebesgue measurable, show that $$F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$$ satisfies $|F(x)-F(y)|\leq C|x-y|^{1/2}$.

Comment: Do you know anything about the integrability of $f$ or can have it have infinite integral?

Comment: @user72415 : you can even take $f \equiv 1$ and your assertion is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true in general. Pick $f(t) = t$. Then $F(x) = x$, and of course $|F(x) - F(y)| = |x - y|$ can never be controlled by $|x - y|^{1/2}$.

If $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, however, then you can prove this result using Cauchy-Schwarz, with the constant $C = \|f\|_{L^2}$.